# Node.js exporting a function that returns an object

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to export a function I defined in a file (`chat.js`) and use it in another file (`main.js`).

This is the code for `chat.js`

```
module.exports.list = function() {
    var chats;

    sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM Chats', {model: Chats}).then((chat) =>{
    console.log(chat);   
   chats = chat
})
return chat;

};
```

When I use it in `main.js`

```
chat.list();
```

It works as expected.

However I get undefined when I store the return object to a variable and `console.log` it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning `chat` object in `synchronous` way but its `asynchronous` query processing.

Use [`promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) chaining or [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

```
module.exports.list = function () {
  var chats;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sequelize
      .query('SELECT * FROM Chats', {model: Chats})
      .then((chat) => {
        console.log(chat);
        resolve(chat);
      })
  })
};
```

**somewhere :**

```
function async test(){

  let result = await chat.list();

  console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: I would avoid use of async/await for this answer. Keep it simple using only Promise.

Comment: Thank you @RIYAJ KHAN. How do I add multiple .query(...)?

Comment: Could you please describe it how you want to use multiple query and where?

Comment: The line after '.query('SELECT * FROM Chats', {model: Chats})'